# Recording loopback doesn't work with alsa

Tags: audio, alsa

I want to record a sound from speakers, not a microphone in my Linux desktop. I'm using Centos 7.

I searched this subject and found this [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1153194) but it only partially works.

I edited my .asoundrc file like the following:

```
# ~/.asoundrc file.
pcm.!default {
type asym
playback.pcm "LoopAndReal" 
capture.pcm "looprec" 
#capture.pcm "hw:0,0" 
} 
...
...
```

And I command:

```
> alsactl kill rescan
> ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -t 5 out.wav
```

But it only works when I set [sound setting -> output tab -> Analog output - Loopback]

The problem is that the speaker sound doesn't work anymore when I set above.

I want to capture a sound with the speaker sound, not with silence! How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using PulseAudio?

Comment: umm.. yes I'm using maybe. but I'm not sure.

Comment: how can i confirm that?

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176399/199301) (although it didn't work for me).