# Raspbian: Check the sound output

Tags: command-line, audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How can I check, from the command line, that the audio line output (of a virtual device created with ALSA plugins) has an audio signal? And check the strength of the signal?

Comment: Are you looking to check conclusively that there is a signal (no hardware faults), or that a signal is being sent (by some software)?

Comment: I'm looking to check that there is a signal, only need to know if it's there and it's strength. Thanks in advice for the contribution, I'm going to edit the question :)

Comment: If you are not using the microphone input (and it has one), then wire audio out to the microphone input, and to the speaker. Then find some signal strength software.

Comment: Tip on links: make the key-word the link. Don't use words like link or here, as a link. This makes the text more readable, and helps with accessibility.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I've found this question on the raspberry forum [Raspberry Pi 3 audio input?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43320/raspberry-pi-3-audio-input) and I think there is no microphone input but you give me an excellent idea to find a solution and thanks for all the tips!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution using the "sox" tool ([sox man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox)). I can use the method proposed in this answer ([Send sound output to application and speaker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175649/send-sound-output-to-application-and-speaker)) to get the signal in an alsa virtual device call "Loopback" while it's also send to the output device and then use sox to find if there is a signal and it's strength:

```
sox -b 16 -t alsa hw:Loopback,1,0 -r 48000 -n stat
```

(-b -> 16 bits signal, -t (alsa hw:Loopback,1,0) -> the virtual device that give me the signal, -r 48000 -> sampling frecuency and -n stat -> analyze the signal)

this command gives an output like that:

```
Input File     : 'hw:Loopback,1,0' (alsa)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM


In:0.00% 00:00:02.47 [00:00:00.00] Out:115k  [-=====|=====-] Hd:3.9 Clip:0  

Samples read:            229376
Length (seconds):      2.389333
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.630951
Minimum amplitude:    -0.630981
Midline amplitude:    -0.000015
Mean    norm:          0.159916
Mean    amplitude:    -0.004383
RMS     amplitude:     0.198459
Maximum delta:         1.176422
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.223984
RMS     delta:         0.278537
Rough   frequency:        10721
Volume adjustment:        1.585
```

when you get signal and like that when there is no signal:

```
Input File     : 'hw:Loopback,1,0' (alsa)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:02:23.70 [00:00:00.00] Out:6.89M [      |      ]        Clip:0

Samples read:          13787136
Length (seconds):    143.616000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.000000
Minimum amplitude:     0.000000
Midline amplitude:     0.000000
Mean    norm:          0.000000
Mean    amplitude:     0.000000
RMS     amplitude:     0.000000
Maximum delta:         0.000000
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.000000
RMS     delta:         0.000000
Rough   frequency:            0
```

The meaning of the "-n stat" tool can be found at ([Sox man page](https://www.scrc.umanitoba.ca/doc/scrchelp/man/sox.html))

Comment: Sorry I though from you comment, you wanted to check the signal (at hardware level). Not just that the software was sending the signal.